# Develop an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I participated in a programming competition at my University. I solved all the questions except this one. Now I am practicing this question to improve my skills. But I can't figure out the algorithm. If there is any algorithm existing please update me. Or any similar algorithm is present then please tell me I will change it according to this question.

This is what I want to do.

- The First line of input is the distance between two points.
- After that, each subsequent line contains a pair of numbers indicating the length of cable and quantity of that cable. These cables are used to join the two points.
- Input is terminated by 0 0

Output:

- The output should contain a single integer representing the minimum number of joints possible to build the requested length of cableway. If no solution possible than print "No solution".

**Sample Input**

```
444
16 2
3 2
2 2
30 3
50 10
45 12
8 12
0 0
```

**Sample Output**

```
10
```

Comment: This question is better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/ and you can solve this with either dynamic programming or network flows. The former is more intuitive

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: to handle the max num per cable, I'd refer to knapsac problem. (where goal is 444, "branch value" is [sum, nb cable taken], and the max weight is applied on each cable type instead of the total nb of cable taken (as is "usually" done)

Comment: I'd use 9 lengths of 50 with knots around the 8 joints for strain-relief: you may be better off explicitly stating the sum of lengths needs to match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I found a solution from "Perfect subset Sum" problem and then made a few changes in it. Here's the code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool dp[100][100];
int sizeOfJoints = -1;
void display(const vector<int>& v)
{
    if (sizeOfJoints == -1)
    {
        sizeOfJoints = v.size() - 1;
    }

    else if (v.size()< sizeOfJoints)
    {
        sizeOfJoints = v.size() - 1;
    }
}

// A recursive function to print all subsets with the
// help of dp[][]. Vector p[] stores current subset.
void printSubsetsRec(int arr[], int i, int sum, vector<int>& p)
{

    // If sum becomes 0
    if (sum == 0)
    {
        display(p);
        return;
    }

    if(i<=0 || sum<0)
        return;

    // If given sum can be achieved after ignoring
    // current element.
    if (dp[i-1][sum])
    {
        // Create a new vector to store path
        //vector<int> b = p;
        printSubsetsRec(arr, i-1, sum, p);
    }

    // If given sum can be achieved after considering
    // current element.
    if (sum >= arr[i-1] && dp[i-1][sum-arr[i-1]])
    {
        p.push_back(arr[i-1]);
        printSubsetsRec(arr, i-1, sum-arr[i-1], p);
        p.pop_back();
    }
}

// all subsets of arr[0..n-1] with sum 0.
void printAllSubsets(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    if (n == 0 || sum < 0)
        return;

    // If sum is 0, then answer is true
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        dp[i][0] = true;

    // If sum is not 0 and set is empty, then answer is false
    for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++)
        dp[0][i] = false;

    // Fill the subset table in botton up manner
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++)
        {
            if(j<arr[i-1])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            if (j >= arr[i-1])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] ||
                           dp[i - 1][j-arr[i-1]];
        }
    }

    if (dp[n][sum] == false)
    {

        return;
    }

    // Now recursively traverse dp[][] to find all
    // paths from dp[n-1][sum]
    vector<int> p;
    printSubsetsRec(arr, n, sum, p);
}

// Driver code
int main()
{



    int input[2000];
    int inputIndex = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int distance = 0;

    cout<< "Enter Input: " <<endl;
    cin>> distance;
    while(true)
    {
        int temp1 = 0;
        int temp2 = 0;
        cin>> temp1;
        cin>> temp2;
        if (temp1 == 0 && temp2 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < temp2; i++)
            input[inputIndex++] = temp1;
    }
    cout<< "Processing output. Please wait: " <<endl;
    printAllSubsets(input, inputIndex, distance);
    if(sizeOfJoints != -1)
        cout<<sizeOfJoints;
    else
        cout<<"No Solution Possible";
    return 0;
}
```